# Show that the subspace of $Y$ obtained by removing a point in $Y$ is homeomorphic to $Y$.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X = \mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology and $Y = \mathbb{R}$ with the countable complement topology. Show that the subspace of $Y$ obtained by removing a point in $Y$ is homeomorphic to $Y$. Is the subspace of $X$ obtained by removing a point in $X$ homeomorphic to $X$?

For the first part, I was thinking this is true just because removing a point doesn't change anything. The open set in $Y$ that contains this discontinuity will still remain open by the definition of co-countable topology. What do you think? Is there a precise way to show they are homeomorphic? I tried to create a mapping $f:Y\to Y\setminus \left\{x\right\}$ but it doesn't seem like the right one.

For the second part, I am not sure. If $J$ is an open interval in $X$ and I remove a point from the interval, I am guessing this ruins the continuity?

Apologies, topology is not my strength.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An arbitrary bijection $f \colon Y \to Y \setminus\{x\}$ is indeed a homeomorphism: it is continuous because the counterimage of a closed set, i.e. a countable set, is again a countable set ($f$ is a bijection) i.e. a closed set. Moreover its inverse is continuous by the same argument.

On the contrary, $X\setminus \{x\}$ is not homeomorphic to $X$, because the former has two connected components, while the latter is connected (a homeomorphism should preserve the number of connected components).